# BeautifulSoup not parsing every tag of the html

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I'm having a problem with BeautifulSoup not completely parsing the html received. I tried with both lxml and html5lib parsers and I had the same problem.

```
html = '<td style="vertical-align: top">1</td> <td style="vertical-align: top"><span class="ui-icon country flg-fr"></span>\t</td><td class="pn"><a class="player-link" href="/Players/25604">Hugo Lloris <span class="incident-wrapper"></span> </a><span class="player-meta-data">29</span><span class="player-meta-data">,  GK  </span></td>   <td class="ShotsTotal ">0\t</td><td class="ShotOnTarget ">0\t</td><td class="KeyPassTotal ">0\t</td><td class="PassSuccessInMatch ">88\t</td><td class="DuelAerialWon ">0\t</td><td class="Touches ">35\t</td><td class="rating ">6.24</td> <td style="text-align: left"><span class="incident-wrapper"></span></td> '

parsed_html = ipdb> BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
<html><head></head><body>1 <span class="ui-icon country flg-fr"></span> <a class="player-link" href="/Players/25604">Hugo Lloris <span class="incident-wrapper"></span> </a><span class="player-meta-data">29</span><span class="player-meta-data">,  GK  </span>   0   0   0   88  0   35  6.24 <span class="incident-wrapper"></span> </body></html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `ipdb`? removing that and using `lxml` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. I execute the following code (using `beautifulsoup4==4.4.1`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td style="vertical-align: top">1</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top"><span class="ui-icon country flg-fr"></span>\t</td>
<td class="pn"><a class="player-link" href="/Players/25604">Hugo Lloris <span class="incident-wrapper"></span> </a><span
        class="player-meta-data">29</span><span class="player-meta-data">,  GK  </span></td>
<td class="ShotsTotal ">0\t</td>
<td class="ShotOnTarget ">0\t</td>
<td class="KeyPassTotal ">0\t</td>
<td class="PassSuccessInMatch ">88\t</td>
<td class="DuelAerialWon ">0\t</td>
<td class="Touches ">35\t</td>
<td class="rating ">6.24</td>
<td style="text-align: left"><span class="incident-wrapper"></span></td>
"""

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
print(html)
```

And I've got the following html printed:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top">1</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top"><span class="ui-icon country flg-fr"></span>    </td>
<td class="pn"><a class="player-link" href="/Players/25604">Hugo Lloris <span class="incident-wrapper"></span> </a><span
        class="player-meta-data">29</span><span class="player-meta-data">,  GK  </span></td>
<td class="ShotsTotal ">0   </td>
<td class="ShotOnTarget ">0 </td>
<td class="KeyPassTotal ">0 </td>
<td class="PassSuccessInMatch ">88  </td>
<td class="DuelAerialWon ">0    </td>
<td class="Touches ">35 </td>
<td class="rating ">6.24</td>
<td style="text-align: left"><span class="incident-wrapper"></span></td>
```

Don't see anything missing.